# What is the best way to get a small amount of chemical from a 4L bottle?

Tags: solvents

I have 4L of multiple chemicals but often only need to work with a few mL at a time. What is the best way to go about this procedure without wasting much of my chemicals?

Pipetting out of the large 4L container is not sustainable, pouring seems dangerous, what else?

Comment: 5ml or 10ml syringe with a long needle

Comment: To answer this question, you should provide additional details such as what size of small volume you are talking about, etc. Additionally, are these chemicals sensitive to the environmental conditions?

Comment: I would pour some of the bottle into a beaker, with the aid of a funnel, then extract the needed amount form there. True, we then have to dispose of the rest of the beaker contents, but we can still keep most of the bottle intact. Using labeled secondary containers may be a good idea as well.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Mathew, I gave a general question and was looking for generalized answers. Serological Pipettes, pouring, and long syringes sound right.

Comment: We used 20 years ago for serial few mL pipetting the special commercial pipetting caps mounted on original 2L chemical bottle flasks. E.g. for methanol or n-hexane. It was simple handle drawing up and down, like a pump, with adjusted volume.